# chrome packaged apps, open new window with button and communicate to the new window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-app

i'm new at chrome packaged apps development and i need support for creating and opening a new window with a button click from the offline packaged app window and communicate between the 2 windows. An example would be very nice.

thanks

Comment: the creation depends on whether you want to open a new browser window or an app window. app windows have no browser ui and contain an html page that is stored within your packaged app.

Comment: sorry, i want open a new app window out of my offline packaged app (it's not opened in the browser) and communicate between the 2 windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
chrome.app.window.create(url, options, function(window){
    //do something with your window
});
```

`url` is the url to the html page, relative to the root of your packaged app directory.
the documentation tells us what to do with the options: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you tell me how i add this the to button? At my background.js add i now: chrome.app.window.create('newWindow.html', {
    "bounds": {
      "left": 100,
      "top": 200,
      "width": 240,
      "height": 260
    }
});

Comment: to open the window at button click you have to put the code in an event handler for the button click. I update my answer :)

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/34OYCFk --> here a screenshot. the help button is opening the new app.window. i have found an solution with your answer --> document.getElementById("helpPage").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('help.html', {
    "bounds": {
      "left": 100,
      "top": 200,
      "width": 240,
      "height": 260
      }
    });
  }, true); --> now i need same help for communicate between the 2 app.windows